# Finding the points of a curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, curves

The equation of a curve C is given by y=-x^2+4x+5.Find the points on the curve C at which the tangent to C passes through the point (0,6) Answer:(-1,0) and (1,8)

I did the question by differentiating the curve (-2x+4) and set it equal to the slope formula (change in y / change in x) and substituting the x in -2x+4 with 0, but with that equation I only got the quadratic equation which -2x^2+2x+1=0, which gives me the second answer.
I then tried doing it without substituting the zero, which gave me both answers. Does this work? Why did my first try only give me one answer? Thanks.

Comment: Slope is $-2x+4$, but you can put $0$ as $x$ only if tangent point has $x=0$. Let tangent point has $x=x_0$, then slope is $-2x_0+4$. Also slope is $\frac{6-f(x_0)}{0-x_0}$. Solve $\frac{6-f(x_0)}{0-x_0}=-2x_0+4$ and you'll find two values of $x_0$. Then $f(x_0)$ give two values of $y$ at tangent points.

Comment: Thank you it's very useful